Import CSV file into Wazuh using Agent
We are working on a project where we had used Elasticsearch to ingest logs from various end points. Now we are trying to do the same using Wazuh.
We already have the Elasticsearch logs, downloaded as csv files. Our objective is, we need these files to be imported into the Wazuh installation, and we would like to perform Anomaly Detection analysis on their contents.
We are clueless as to how this is to be done. Wazuh Agents are installed on multiple machines, and are collecting all logs/ events/ Alerts in real time; While we need to have the old data already collected in Elastic -> dumped into CSV files -> imported/ ingested into Wazuh.
Any help in this regard will be appreciated.
Thanks & Regards,
